# Is there ERC20 token test library?

Tags: truffle, erc-20, testing

I have a custom ERC20 token project and I would like to cover the token behaviour with tests. As the ERC20 interface is standardized I wonder whether there are some libraries to test ERC20 functionality or to help me with it?

I use truffle in my project so I prefer tests specifically for this framework but it is not required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't found out nothing similar to what I was looking for. Hence I have came up with the custom package:

https://github.com/CryptoverseRocks/token-test-suite

With this package all the tests are already written. Just configure and run the test suite contained!

Comment: This is great, but I have a few issues using it 1) the `import` statement no longer works, and 2) I am not sure how I'm supposed to be getting those test addresses

Comment: Wow, so somebody is actually trying to use it? That's great. Feel free to open up an issue on github and let's discuss it there.

Comment: You have done great job! However it does not work with truffle 5.0 and web3 1.0 anymore. I have updated it to support new truffle: https://github.com/dukei/token-test-suite

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the heavily audited ERC20 token contracts found on [github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens](https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens) and [github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity). You'll find [extensive tests](https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens/blob/master/test/humanStandardToken.js) using truffle.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen those. The major problem with them they are not designed for code reuse (the tests). So the only way to use them is to copy&paste (and customize). That's not good.

Comment: @mancze oh gotcha. I haven't seen anything out there like you described. However, it should be pretty simple to take those tests and turn it into a library.

Answer (score 1):

If you have existing tests and you don't want to figure out how to integrate @mancze's solution, read on.

The key is to use `truffle`'s builtin `ERC20` contract using `artifacts.require("ERC20");`

```
const { constants } = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers')
const ERC20 = artifacts.require("ERC20");
```

then your test will look like

```
contract('Your_Contract', (accounts) => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    `let erc20Instance = await ERC20.new();`
  })

  it('ERC20 should work', async () => {
      await expectRevert(
          erc20Instance.transfer(constants.ZERO_ADDRESS, 42, { from: accounts[1] }),
          'ERC20: transfer to the zero address'
      )
  })
})
```

This was tested with versions:

1. "@openzeppelin/test-helpers": "^0.5.5",
2. "truffle": "^5.1.24"

so YMMV!

Comment: Is this still valid?
I got `Error: Could not find artifacts for ERC20 from any sources`. Do I need to add any config first?